# Visual studio to exist-db connection

Tags: asp.net, xml, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, exist-db

I'm planning to use exist-db for my project on a web content management system. I need to use asp.net as well. Can someone provide references that will help to connect to a exist-db from visual studio?

Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In general: the best way for connecting to the eXist-db is using the REST interface (or better: RestXQ extension). This is the best solution for all programming languages.

eXist-db does provide a SOAP interface (with the corresponding WSDL files) which is a good fit for a .net context but this interface is rather old/outdated.